# getrusage() not giving the correct rss value for the Child process

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, getrusage

I have written the following code in C++ to run a C++ code in a sandboxed env and then getting its memory usage

```
int main() {
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1){
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
        cout<<"I am the child process"<<endl;
        const char* command = "/bin/sh";
        const char* arg1 = "sh";
        const char* arg2 = "-c";
        const char* arg3 = "/user_code/myprogram < /user_code/input.txt > /user_code/output1.txt";
        
        execlp(command, arg1, arg2, arg3, (char*)NULL);

        perror("execl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"I am the parent process"<<endl;

        int status;
        struct rusage ru;

        wait(&status);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &ru);
            cout << "Memory usage (in KB): " << ru.ru_maxrss << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Child process did not exit as expected." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code prints:

```
I am the parent process
I am the child process
Memory usage (in KB): 3584
```

That is very less RSS. When I run the same logic in python I get the rss as 9440 KB which is accurate when compared to my submission on codeforces

I tired running the logic on python. There it is giving the correct response.

My python code that is giving the correct response:

```
import subprocess
import resource



p = subprocess.Popen("/user_code/myprogram < /user_code/input.txt > /user_code/output2.txt", shell=True)
p.wait()
print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN).ru_maxrss)
```

This prints 9440 KB.

Comment: To begin with, you need to check if `getrusage` fails or not. Secondly, the Python `Popen`  class will fork the whole Python interpreter itself, which of course uses lots more memory than your small and simple test program.

Comment: Its not a small and simple test program. It is this code. Which is decent enough: https://codeforces.com/contest/1888/submission/229438258. And getrusage is not failing.

Comment: if you see the first test case you will see this: `Time: 0 ms, memory: 9300 KB`. I need a memory close to that

Comment: But ***why***? Why do you need "memory close to that" value? What is the original and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Why isn't it better to only use as much memory as needed? Why do you need to waste memory? Please [edit] your question to give us more details, and make sure that the question is self-contained.

Comment: Also please take the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Then please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, the memory limit for so-called competitions are *limits*, not targets you must reach. And on that note, the code you link to is not to be used as an example of good code, for competitions or otherwise. That code is actually not valid C++ code, since it's using reserved symbols. It's just the typical bad code that seems to permeate such sites. If you presented code like that to me as a teacher or an interviewer, I would fail and dismiss you immediately.

Comment: I am making an online judge so there I would get such submissions only. CP submissions are like this only. So I am just asking for a way to get a very close memory usage value.

Comment: Then you should not just use `_popen`. That opens up the system to a great number of security problems. Unless this is for some kind of class assignment or project, such a project is much more advanced and harder to handle than most imagine (that you have problems understanding that a relatively small and simple C++ program takes up much less memory than a full Python interpreter is a sign of that). And it's an area that is already overcrowded, and such sites in general just promote bad and invalid coding habits, so what's the use?

Comment: For god sake just accept you dont know the answer. Someone else will reply. Stop writing something completely diverted from the topic. Why should I even restrict someone from writing any code. I should be able to analyze memory no matter what.